# Como obrigar a largura máxima da tabela?

Tags: html, css, table

Tem como definir a largura a ser ocupado pela tabela? forçando ela a fazer uma quebra de linha e continuar quando atinge essa largura máxima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem, claro, se quiser direto no HTML:

```html
<table class = "tabela" style = "max-width:100px;">
    <tr>
        <td>teste de tamanho máximo da largura de uma tabela
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/MaxWidth.html).

Ma o ideal é ter o `style` se referenciando à classe `tabela` (neste exemplo, você dá o nome que quiser, ou pode usar um `id` para identificar este elemento específico) em um arquivo CSS separado.

Comment: Tentei aqui e não funcionou, eu fiz um projeto em php + myslq pra pegar os dados e jogar na tela, como são muitos, mais de 20, ele acaba vazando. eu usei o laço "for(){}" pra repetir os trechos que aparecem, tipo isso: 

<table border="1" >

 <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){
  ?>

  <tr>
  <?php for($tel=3; $tel<= 16; $tel++){?>
  <td><?php echo $dado["nome"];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $dado["$tel"];?></td>


  <?php } ?>
  </tr> 
  <?php } ?>
 </table>
Me esticando um pouco mais, isso esta correto?

Comment: Você viu que funciona aí em cima? Você deveria ter colocado todas informações necessárias na pergunta, o que desejava de fato, incluindo este código e possivelmente o HTML gerado por este código, que fica muito mais fácil de verificar. Que por sinal não tem o que eu respondi, então não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Sim realmente funciona, quando eu chamo somente 14 telefones, quando eu coloco mais que 14, ele continua vazando, acho que meu laço esta errado, mas obrigado mesmo assim :D

Comment: Tenta algumas coisas que poderiam ser feitas para evitar isto mas elas vão causar outros problemas piores. Não dá para colocar 14 elefantes dentro de um fusca. Dá para por 14 cachorros mas não é o que você quer.

Comment: Verdade... vou estudar um pouco mais, comecei com php a pouco tempo, Muito obrigado

Comment: Você não tem problema algum com o PHP, é só o HTML (e possivelmente CSS). Claro que seja que tecnologia for, seja que conhecimento máximo que alguém tem, não pode escrever a bíblia em uma folha de papel. Tem soluções, mas é algo mais complexo, vai além do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Vou tentar resolver isso sem o <table></table>, se der o resultado que eu espero, atualizo aqui :D

Comment: Isso é uma excelente ideia, se não é uma tabela que está fazendo, não use `table`.